# How to capture WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK event with wxPython?

Tags: windows, wxpython

I'm using wxPython. I want to detect mouse events on the caption bar. I noticed that there is a event called WM_NCMOUSEHOVER under windows. But I cannot find corresponding event in wxPython. Here is the question, how can I capture those non-client events with wxPython?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to get mouse events from the frame title bar. The closest I got was EVT_MOTION. However, you might be able to use a wx.Timer  in combination with wx.GetMousePosition(). See [Capturing mouse events outside wx.Frame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705201/capturing-mouse-events-outside-wx-frame-in-python) for more info.